# SQL Order By not working properly

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

I have a table like this

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_LandRigs](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(700000,1) NOT NULL,
    [Company] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [Rig] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [RigType] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [DrawWorks] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [TopDrive] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [RotaryTable] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [MudPump] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [MaxDD] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Operator] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [Country] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [Location] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [OPStatus] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [CreatedByID] [int] NULL,
    [CreatedByName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_LandRigs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And I am trying to get data from MaxDD column in Descending order

```
SELECT  distinct "MaxDD" FROM [tbl_LandRigs] ORDER BY "MaxDD" Desc
```

But this returns data in following order
[image]
According to my calculation 4000 must be the first value followed by others.But this results astonished me.Can any one help me out in this?

Comment: You are storing them as text(`nvarchar`), that why you get [lexographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are storing them as text(`nvarchar`), that's why you get [lexographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). That means every character is compared with each other from left to right. Hence `4000` is "higher" than `30000` (the last zero doesn't matter since the first 4 is already higher than the 3).

So the correct way is to store it as a numeric value. However, that seems to be impossible since you also use values like `16.000 with 4.1/2"DP`. Then i would add another column, one for the numeric value you want to order by and the other for the textual representation.

Answer (score 3):

As `MaxDD` is a `varchar`, not a number it is sorted in lexicographical order (i.e. ordered by the first character, then second, ...), not numerical. You should convert it to a numerical value

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is due to the nvarchar type.

Try this:

```
SELECT  distinct "MaxDD" FROM [tbl_LandRigs] ORDER BY CAST ("MaxDD" as Int)
```

Comment: this will fail since `MaxDD` has at least one not numeric value `16.000 with 4.1/2"DP`