# Order by not working as expected in Sql Server 2008?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, c#-2.0

I know this is a well asked question and I do find some answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460919/sql-order-by-not-working-properly) but this doesn't solve my problem. Please see attached screen shots.
1. [image]
The result of the query running in Sql server management studio and
2. [image]
Data loaded into a form (Windows forms application, C# & Dot Net) using the SAME query. I read about "lexographical order" from above link. Even if considering this, my question is, why the data is showing in such strange order in the form?

Code I used to load data into ListView is:

```
private void LoadDataInListView(List<MyClass> listMyClass)
{
     List<ListViewItem> itemList = new List<ListViewItem>();
     lvwList.Items.Clear();
     for (int i = 0; i < listMyClass.Count; i++)
     {
          ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("");
          item.SubItems.Add(listMyClass[i].Name.ToString());
          item.SubItems.Add("Ready");
          item.Tag = listMyClass[i];
          itemList.Add(item);
     }
     lvwList.Items.AddRange(itemList.ToArray());
}
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
As requested, my actual code to load data into list.

```
public List<MegaFileInfoBO> GetAllMegaFileInfo()
        {
            List<MegaFileInfoBO> listUserInfo = new List<MegaFileInfoBO>();
            using (SqlConnection connection = MiniRapsDatabase.CreateConnection())
            {
                SqlCommand command = MiniRapsDatabase.CreateCommand(connection);

                MiniRapsDatabase.CreateStoredprocedure(command, "GetAllMegaFileInfo_SP");

                SqlDataReader reader = MiniRapsDatabase.ExecuteReader(command);

                if (reader != null)
                {

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        MegaFileInfoBO userInfo = new MegaFileInfoBO();

                        userInfo.ImportDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["ImportDate"]);
                        userInfo.ImportedBy = (String)reader["ImportedBy"];
                        userInfo.MegaFileDescription = (String)reader["MegaFileDescription"];
                        userInfo.MegaFileID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["MegaFileID"]);
                        userInfo.MegaFileName = (String)reader["MegaFileName"];
                        userInfo.RootImageDirectory = (String)reader["RootImageDirectory"];
                        userInfo.EnteredBy = (String)(reader["EnteredBy"].Equals(DBNull.Value) ? String.Empty : reader["EnteredBy"]);
                        userInfo.DoubleKeyedBy = (String)(reader["DoubleKeyedBy"].Equals(DBNull.Value) ? String.Empty : reader["DoubleKeyedBy"]);

                        listUserInfo.Add(userInfo);
                    }
                }
            }
            listUserInfo.Sort(new MegaFileInfoBOComparer());

            return listUserInfo;
        }
```

Comment: The value in listMyClass is out of order.  CAn you post the code on how did you populate the listMyClass list.

Comment: `listUserInfo.Sort(new MegaFileInfoBOComparer());` what's that?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Are the items coming in sorted order?

Comment: After adding all items to the list, you call `listUserInfo.Sort(new MegaFileInfoBOComparer());`.  This brings two things to mind: 1) Why does the DB order matter if you sort it in the application layer, and 2) What is the sort criteria used in the application layer? (And a side one - if the comparator is idempotent, as it _should_ be, don't you just use a cached copy?)